# What can I use as a standard c++ base class for RAII+seperatio of concerns purposes

Tags: c++, oop, std

I am looking to expose a class which implements RAII purpose and toggles some global state. For all intents and purposes the class implementation should be hidden. In other words, the class declaration looks like this:

```
class ScopedToggleSomething {
public:
    ScopedToggleSomething();
    ~ScopedToggleSomething();
};
```

and it will be used as such:

```
ScopedToggleSomething localToggle;
```

this is fine, but it's verbose. If there was some standard base class with virtual constructor/destructor, I could have made declaration much simpler, such as:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::object> ScopedToggleSomethingFactory();
```

and use it like so:

```
auto localToggle = ScopedToggleSomethingFactory();
```

and that allows me to hide even a class declaration. `std::object` doesn't exist obviously, it's just to make a point. My question is, whether there is some standard base class that would allow me to implement such pattern and avoid unneeded verbosity in header. `boost::noncopyable` comes to mind, but it has no virtual destructor, so won't work.

*EDIT*: I guess I was not clear that what I was looking is not only RIAA, but also "hide" the actual implementation of functionality outside the header, and only declare bare minimum necessary to use the class

Comment: how is `ScopedToggleSomething localToggle;` more verbose than `auto localToggle = ScopedToggleSomethingFactory();` ? just trying to understand what your are looking for

Comment: What is the problem with `auto localToggle = std::make_unique<ScopedToggleSomething>();`?

Comment: RAII classes rarely need virtual destructors, and there is no such thing as virtual constructor.

Comment: By saying "verbose" I referred to header declaration of class vs declaration of a single function.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard type that you can use, and if you think about what RAII is, it makes sense that there isn't.

RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) is the idiom where the objects constructor acquires some resource, and the objects destructor releases said resource.  This means you need to actually write code in those special member functions.  Inheriting from some type doesn't help you with this because that type can't know what your invariant's are.  Only you know that so you have to be the one the writes the code.

This is different from something like `boost::noncopyable` because `boost::noncopyable` removes functionality.  It uses the fact that if the base has a deleted special member function then anything that derives from it will get that same special member deleted for them.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I guess RIAA is not the only pattern I was looking to use. I am also trying to separate concerns, e.g.: have class implemented outside header, so that implementation is hidden

Comment: @galets C++ isn't great about hiding things.  One of the best idioms for that is the [PIMPL idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)

Comment: But if you had ever used PIMPL in more than a demonstrator app, you will think again about PIMPL :-) BTW: I am unclear what "hiding" really means here. Want to make the implementation "invisible", maybe to deliver only compiled libraries or to think about type erasure or other ideas. Only speculation...

Comment: @klaus the "hiding" concept I'm looking for is not necessarily about concealing what code does, it's more about not exposing what's not necessary to expose. It's about making it easier to understand what code does by only declaring what's essential. PIMPL idiom is fine, but so is my original suggestion. I was just looking to make it even more concise